# Showing the same file in both columns of a Sublime Text window

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext4

When I have 2 columns set in a Sublime Text window, can I display the same file in both columns?

Answer (score 347, accepted):

**EDIT**

With the release of Sublime Text 4, there is now a feature called Split View that you can access a couple different ways. Via the menu system, you can simply use **`File -> Split View`**. You can also right-click on a tab and select **`Split View`** from the context menu. It automatically opens a new pane with a new view of the file currently selected.

You should be aware that unlike the new pane described below, the new Split View pane is temporary. This means that if you click on another tab or open a new file, the split view disappears. However, the new view into the file remains open as a separate tab, so to reopen the pane (or compare any open file(s)), select the tab you want on the left, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click (<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-click on macOS) on the other tab(s) you want to compare, and each one will be displayed in its own pane.

If want to have two (or more) "permanent" panes that will stay open regardless of which tab you click on, just follow the directions below.

---

**Original Answer**

<sup>(For Sublime Text 3)</sup>

Yes, you can. When a file is open, click on **`File -> New View Into File`**. You can then drag the new tab to the other pane and view the file twice.

There are several ways to create a new pane. As described in other answers, on Linux and Windows, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> (<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd><kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> on OS X), which corresponds to **`View → Layout → Columns: 2`** in the menu. If you have the excellent [`Origami`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Origami) plugin installed, you can use **`View → Origami → Pane → Create → Right`**, or the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> chord on Windows/Linux (replace <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with <kbd>⌘</kbd> on OS X).

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+2 shortcut for split screen and drag the file over

Comment: You can also use Windows+Ctrl+arrow key to arrange windows.

Comment: The cmd in the next post works - shift + Alt + 2 to split into 2 screens, not this one below.

Comment: @LEDFantom When you say this answer doesn't work, what do you mean? The OP already knew how to create split windows, which is why I didn't explain how to do that in my answer. I'm not sure what the downvote is for.

Comment: @MattDMo , I see what you meant now.  How do I remove the down vote?

Comment: @LEDFantom I just edited the post, so you can remove it if you wish. Thanks!

Comment: It makes me sad that this option is in the File menu and not the View menu.

Comment: `File --> New View Into File` seems to be gone entirely in Sublime Text 4. :(

Comment: Found it! In Sublime Text 4: `File --> Split View`.

Comment: @GabrielStaples thanks for the tip, I've expanded my answer to include Split View.

Answer (score 94):

Its <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> to split into 2 screens. More options are found under the menu item View -> Layout.
Once the screen is split, you can open files using the shortcuts:
1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (From existing directories within sublime) or
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>(Browse directory)

Comment: To expand, CTRL + P will allow you to "open" the same file more than once.

Comment: CTRL + O will not

Answer (score 74):

Inside sublime editor,Find the Tab named `View`,

```
View --> Layout --> "select your need"
```

Comment: `View --> Layout --> "select your need" `                                                 select your needs = [single,columns,rows,grids]. So this means the options available when you go to Layout .try out first ,Tested in Sublime 2.

Comment: appreciate the menu navigation instead of just a shortcut which happens to work for some users and doesn't explain what sublime feature is in use - which the menu clearly defines. :)

Comment: This should be the only accepted, this is what worked for me. The accepted one doesn't work anymore. Probably it doesn't work in current versions.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a simple plugin to "open / close a splitter" into the current file, as found in other editors:

```python
import sublime_plugin

class SplitPaneCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        w = self.window
        if w.num_groups() == 1:
            w.run_command('set_layout', {
                'cols': [0.0, 1.0],
                'rows': [0.0, 0.33, 1.0],
                'cells': [[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 2]]
            })
            w.focus_group(0)
            w.run_command('clone_file')
            w.run_command('move_to_group', {'group': 1})
            w.focus_group(1)
        else:
            w.focus_group(1)
            w.run_command('close')
            w.run_command('set_layout', {
                'cols': [0.0, 1.0],
                'rows': [0.0, 1.0],
                'cells': [[0, 0, 1, 1]]
            })
```

Save it as `Packages/User/split_pane.py` and bind it to some hotkey:

```
{"keys": ["f6"], "command": "split_pane"},
```

If you want to change to vertical split change with following

```
        "cols": [0.0, 0.46, 1.0],
        "rows": [0.0, 1.0],
        "cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 6):

I regularly work on the same file in 2 different positions. I solved this in Sublime Text 3 using [origami](https://github.com/SublimeText/Origami) and [chain](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Chain%20of%20Command) with some additional config.

My workflow is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> splits the view of the file in two (horizontal) panes with the lower one active. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> to toggle between the panes. When done ensure the lower pane is the active and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> to close the duplicated view and the pane.

In sublime global settings (not origami settings!) add

```
"origami_auto_close_empty_panes": true,
```

Add the following shortcuts

```
  { "keys": ["ctrl+k", "2"], 
    "command": "chain", 
    "args": {
      "commands": [
        ["create_pane", {"direction": "down"}],
        ["clone_file_to_pane", {"direction": "down"}],
      ],
    }
  },

  { "keys": ["ctrl+k", "o"], "command": "focus_neighboring_group" },
```

Comment: to make the `chain` command work (seen in the shortcut), you will also need the [Chain of Command package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Chain%20of%20Command) installed.

Comment: @wehal3001 Thanks, updated (also updated the globals settings, where the wrong setting was pasted).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to use [Origami](https://github.com/SublimeText/Origami). Its a great plugin for splitting the screen. For better information on keyboard short cuts install it and after restarting Sublime text open **Preferences`->`Package Settings `->` Origami `->` Key Bindings - Default**

For specific to your question I would suggest you to see the short cuts related to cloning of files in the above mentioned file.

Answer (score 3):

**View -> Layout -> Choose one option or use shortcut**

```
Layout        Shortcut

Single        Alt + Shift + 1
Columns: 2    Alt + Shift + 2
Columns: 3    Alt + Shift + 3
Columns: 4    Alt + Shift + 4
Rows: 2       Alt + Shift + 8
Rows: 3       Alt + Shift + 9
Grid: 4       Alt + Shift + 5
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Kinda little late but I tried to extend [@Tobia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23957730/sublime-editor-split-screen-put-same-file-on-both-windows/35158307#35158307) to set the layout "horizontal" or "vertical" driven by the command argument e.g.

```
{"keys": ["f6"], "command": "split_pane", "args": {"split_type": "vertical"} }
```

Plugin code:

```
import sublime_plugin


class SplitPaneCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, split_type):
        w = self.window
        if w.num_groups() == 1:
            if (split_type == "horizontal"):
                w.run_command('set_layout', {
                    'cols': [0.0, 1.0],
                    'rows': [0.0, 0.33, 1.0],
                    'cells': [[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 2]]
                })
            elif (split_type == "vertical"):
                w.run_command('set_layout', {
                    "cols": [0.0, 0.46, 1.0],
                    "rows": [0.0, 1.0],
                    "cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1]]
                })

            w.focus_group(0)
            w.run_command('clone_file')
            w.run_command('move_to_group', {'group': 1})
            w.focus_group(1)
        else:
            w.focus_group(1)
            w.run_command('close')
            w.run_command('set_layout', {
                'cols': [0.0, 1.0],
                'rows': [0.0, 1.0],
                'cells': [[0, 0, 1, 1]]
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to edit same file in Split mode. 
It is best explained in following youtube video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2cMEeE1aOk

Comment: The video has been removed. This is why SO doesn't encourage answers which are just links.